# Join jsonb column with top level columns in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I join jsonb column value with top level values like ID
for example

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY,
    data jsonb
);
```

If I run the following query: `SELECT * FROM things;`, I will get this

```
id | data
-----------
1  | {"key": "value}
```

How can I join get something with this format instead:

```
id | key
-----------
1  | value
```

i could do SELECT AS but, then i have to select all the keys manually and if one of the values are null its still returned as null value

```
id | key
-----------
1  | null
```

how can i select all jsonb data like i described above while ignoring null values?

Comment: "*I have to select all the keys manually*" - in SQL, the number and names (and types) of the columns of a result have to be known to the database **before** executing the statement (this is done when the statement is parsed). You can't have a dynamic number of columns that depends on the values that are evaluated when the query is executed (and you can't have a different number of columns in each row, which you implicitly expect with that data model). You can easily get all the keys (with non-null values) as rows though.

Answer (score 1):

use the `->>` operator

```
select id, data->>'key' as key from things;
```

**Edit**

> Problem with that is that i have to select every key, and if key is
>   null its still shown, can't i just select ...

filter it using another condition in `where` clause

```
select id, data->>'key' as key from things where nullif(data->>'key','')
is not null;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=411272ad5373a274ee5f62887ead6664)

Comment: Problem with that is that i have to select every key, and if key is null its still shown, can't i just select everything like that while skipping null values?

Comment: @julian : You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54808820/edit)  your question and add all the scenarios you expect and the desired output that covers all those. We can't assume  what exactly you want based on your current sample data in the question.

Comment: @julian : It is not clear. What exactly do you mean "one of the keys are null" ? You mean the `data` column is null  or  `value` is empty? show the column in table for the scenario and the rows you want to see and rows you want to exclude.

Comment: yes i mean the value, when values are null they are still returned as null, when i select then with SELECT AS not with SELECT *

Comment: great but thats not what i meant, i mean skip the key not the entire column, i just want to ignore values if they are null, not entire columns